# How to add component on the right side of the sidebar?

Tags: css, vue.js

I have the following code:

```
<template>
    <div class="main">
        <sidebar />
        <router-view />
    </div>
</template>
```

The sidebar has width of `260px`. I want the component that being add to the router-view to no be "behind" the sidebar. It should be on the right side of the sidebar. I thought of adding margin-left of `260px` but I'm not sure if it's robust enough. What would be the best way to add the component on the right side of the sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

If the sidebar width is fixed, then the best and easiest way is just to use margin-left. Otherwise, you can add a window resize listener to adjust margin-left dynamically from javascript by calculating the sidebar width.

You also might be intereseted with Vue component frameworks like [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers/) or [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/layout/drawer#Introduction)